# Проблема с наложение изображения на фон сайта

Tags: css, html5

У меня проблема с наложение картинки на фон сайта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
body {
  background-image: url(images/fon.png);
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: Тут ясновидящих нет, опиши проблему так, чтобы было понятно, что именно хотел реализовать и что не получается?

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  background-image: url(images/fon.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

`background-repeat: no-repeat;` - не повторять изображение.

`background-position: center;` - позиция по центру.

Можешь позицию менять в процентах, пример: `background-position: 45% 54%;` - 45% - по ширине, 54% - по высоте.

Comment: @Давид Манжула Твоя правка особо ничего не меняет, но, не забывайте в CSS после каждой строчки со свойством ставить «;»